# Parsing output of psutil.virtual_memory()

Tags: python

I want to only return the "used" value of `psutil.virtual_memory()

Output

```
svmem(total=8216567808, available=6662995968, percent=18.9, used=1231118336, free=5789609984, active=1523171328, inactive=663773184, buffers=49303552, cached=1146535936, shared=67084288, slab=101306368)
```

Comment: Looks like a named tuple. The values can be accessed by index or name: `output.used`.

Comment: Thank you `psutil.virtual_memory().used` worked great.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
used_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
```

## output in MB

```
print(used_memory >> 20)
```

## output in GB

```
print(psutil.virtual_memory().used >> 30)
```